# Calling chart JS with PHP Data (file structure)

Tags: php, chart.js

Morning all, bit of a long winded one so I'll try to keep it brief.

I'm experimenting with HTML that calls continual PHP themes, rather than writing the code in each HTML (php) page.

For instance, home.php looks like this:

```html
<?php include("includes/config.php");?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <?php include("includes/head-tag.php");?>
</head>

<body id="page-top">
    <?php include("includes/nav.php");?>

  
  <div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <ul class="sidebar navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i><span style="margin-left:5px">Dashboard</span></a></li> 
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="assets.php"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-server"></i><span style="margin-left:5px">Assets</span></a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="people.php"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-user"></i><span style="margin-left:5px">People</span></a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i></i><span style="margin-left:5px">Reports</span></a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fas fa-cogs"></i></i><span style="margin-left:5px">Settings</span></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="logout.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></i><span style="margin-left:5px">Log Out</span></a></li>
    </ul>


    <div id="content-wrapper">

      <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Breadcrumbs-->
        <?php include("includes/breadcrumb.php");?>
  
     <!-- Card Deck -->
     <?php include("cards.php");?>


        <!-- DataTables Example -->
        <?php include("charts.php");?>
 

      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->

      <!-- Sticky Footer -->
   <?php include("includes/footer.php");?>


    </div>
    <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

  </div>
  <!-- /#wrapper -->

  <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
  <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
  </a>

  <!-- Logout Modal -->
  <?php include("includes/logout.php");?>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <?php include("includes/scripts.php");?>

</body>
</html>
```

You'll see that half way down, I have charts.php which is simply the HTML to chart.js (bootstrap themed) like so:

```html
<div class="card mb-4 border-0">    
        <div class="card-deck">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header"><i class="fa fa-chart-pie"></i> Assets By Type</div>
            <div class="card-body">
            <canvas id="doughnutChart"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
            <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header"><i class="fa fa-chart-pie"></i> Phone Models</div>
            <div class="card-body">
            <canvas id="doughnutChartPho"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> Total Laptops</div>
            <div class="card-body">
            <canvas id="doughnutChartLap"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
            <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

In the root directly (where charts.php is) I have a folder to js/charts/pie.js which contains this:

```js
//doughnut  
  var ctxD = document.getElementById("doughnutChart").getContext('2d');
  var myLineChart = new Chart(ctxD, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: <?php echo json_encode($json); ?>,
      datasets: [{
        data: <?php echo json_encode($json2); ?>,
        backgroundColor: ["#F7464A", "#46BFBD", "#FDB45C", "#949FB1", "#4D5360"],
        hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF5A5E", "#5AD3D1", "#FFC870", "#A8B3C5", "#616774"],
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true
    }
  });
```

and the php code which I place at the top of charts.php is this:

```html
$stmt=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM asset_details");
$stmt->execute(); 
$json= [];
$json2= [];
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 extract($row);
 $json[]= $type;
 $json2[]= (int)$manufacturer;
}
echo json_encode($json);
echo json_encode($json2);
?>
```

Those two echos appear on the page home page in the right place (ie, directly above the first chart), but the chart doesn't show. I suspect it is because of the files being in different locations rather than in one code block.

Could I add the php query to the top of pie.js instead? If I use pretend data in the dataset and labels, the chart appears.

Comment: `Could I add the php query to the top of pie.js instead?` Not unless you have explicitly set up .js files to be handled by PHP, which is usually not the case, and probably not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

ChartJS expects the data in a comma separated statement, such as:

```
 data: 5, 7, 8, 9;
```

I suspect the json_encode is confusing it, and would suggest you return strings, rather than arrays:

```
$stmt=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM asset_details");
$stmt->execute(); 
$json= "";
$json2= [];
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    extract($row);
    $json .= "'".$type."',";
    $json2 .= (int)$manufacturer.",";
}
echo $json; // should be 'Red','Green','Blue' ... 
echo $json2; // should be 5,6,9,4 ... etc 
?>
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting, thanks for this. I suspect you are correct. However, the echo test now shows: '1','2',Array1,1, and no chart data still.

Comment: Can you show the output from "SELECT type,manufacturer FROM asset_details" ?

Comment: Sure, I get this: type manufacturer
                          1      1
                          2      1

Comment: that doesn't seem consistent with the previous output, but try changing the second line to `json2 .= $manufacturer.",";`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have been unwell the last few days. I appreciate your help though, but this still doesn't seem to work. I can see the echos are behaving correctly in as much as I get the ' ' and , , between the data. I also have a  Notice: Array to string conversion on line 9 which is the $json2 .= $manufacturer.",";

Comment: You may need to iterate through the data .. depending on how it's structured `foreach ($manufacturer as $tmp) { $json2 .= (int)$tmp.","; }` replaces the previous line `json2 .= $manufacturer.",";`